# What should I load into data segment?

Tags: assembly, emulation, dos, i386

I'm working on emulator, which should emulated specific program. I have COM file and source file. Now I need to emulate this specific instruction (this is what I can see in DosBox debugger):

```
mov cl, [017B]        8A 0E 7B 01
```

I know it means to move value from `DS` (data segment) with offset `017B` into `CL` register. But what should be in `DS`?

Program I'm trying to emulate (source file):

```
.386p

.model tiny

code    segment use16
    assume cs:code
    org  100h

begin:
  mov ax, 3h
  int 10h
...
  mov cl, byte ptr ds:[keylen]   <-- This is the instruction I'm talking about
...
  int 20h           

keylen db 13
key1 db 20h, 3ah, 23h, 32h, 0bh, 3dh, 1fh, 13h, 4ch, 19h, 05h, 07h, 07h, 00h
key2 db 00h, 0ah, 11h, 08h, 03h, 1dh, 1ah, 08h, 04h, 2ch, 3fh, 33h, 1ah, 41h
key3 db 01h, 00h, 08h, 0bh, 0ch, 07h, 0ah, 05h, 02h, 09h, 06h, 03h, 04h, 00h

code    ends
end begin
```

What should I save into `DS` when I start my program? Only think I'm doing now is to set `DS = CS = ES = SS = SPECIFIC_ADDRESS`

Comment: With a COM program (tiny model with an org of  100h`) CS=DS=ES=SS=the segment of the PSP you use for the program before you transfer control to it. This only applies to COM (not EXE)

Comment: This may be of some use to you: http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm (plus maybe PSP structure, if the code is fetching something from `cs:0000-cs:00FF` range).

Comment: @MichaelPetch I know, it is COM program

Answer (score 2):

For a .COM program like the one you have, there's no need to want to setup any of the segment registers yourself. The operating system program loader has already set them all pointing at the start of your program.

The instruction `mov cl, byte ptr ds:[keylen]` will work as is.
You don't even have to specify the segment explicitly. You can also write `mov cl, byte ptr [keylen]` or even `mov cl, [keylen]`.

Now if you insist on setting up the `DS` segmentregister manually, you could write:

```
mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax
```

Another way would be:

```
mov ah, 62h   ;DOS.GetPSP
int 21h       ; -> BX
mov ds, bx
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm not sure if you get point of my question. I'm trying to emulate this program and I know where I should point DS. But I don't know what should be in whole data section.